# Can't connect to websocket server (spring)

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp

I try to implement plain websocket with Stomp (and not SockJS) with a Spring server and an Angular client.

Here is my code to enable websocket in Spring:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler heartBeatScheduler() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker('/status')
                .setHeartbeatValue(new long[] { 10000, 10000})
                .setTaskScheduler(heartBeatScheduler());

        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes('/');
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint('/myapp-websocket').setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages.anyMessage().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But I can't connect to it, when I try in angular with stompjs the connection is never done.
When I test with wscat `wscat -c "ws://localhost:4200/api/myapp-websocket"` (the /api/ is good btw) there is no response, it's always trying to connect without success.

What is wrong here ?

Edit: Here is the two dependency I use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Edit:

I also try to change `messages.anyMessage().authenticated();` to `messages.anyMessage().permitAll();` but same behavior I still can't connect to my websocket..

Comment: Do you get errors in the console ? if yes please provide it

Comment: No error in the console, I have only this log: `Tue Feb 18 2020 14:58:29 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale) "Opening Web Socket..."` and then the connexion is never opened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you send client requests from different port, that means your client is on different origin, for that you must add some headers on server side. Also on connect websocket sends POST to endpoint, which you must enable. I don't know exactly what endpoints are being sent, check in you console, and then add them to `antMatchers`

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/status**", "/topic", "/myapp-websocket/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();

    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("*"));
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Comment: In configure method you have written cors disable and why you have corsconfiguration bean? Currently I have cors enable but I'm not able connect to webscoket. can you help what changes I'll have to make If I have enabled the cors.